# ASP.NET MVC using C# and data tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

> `Blo`ente`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFQgu.png)
>
> namespace believe.Controllers {
> public class ProductController : Controller
> {
> private readonly IUnitOfWork _context;
> private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;
> public ProductController(IUnitOfWork context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
> {
> _context = context;
> _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
> }
>
> ```
>     public IActionResult Index()
>     {
>        
>         return View();
>     }
>     //GET
>    
>   
>     public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
>     {
>         if (id is null or 0)
>         {
>             return NotFound();
>         }
>         var obj = _context.Product.GetFirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
>         return View(obj);
>     }
>     [HttpPost]
>     public IActionResult DeletePOST(int? id)
>     {
>         var obj = _context.Product.GetFirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
>         if (obj == null)
>         {
>             return NotFound();
>         }
>         _context.Product.Remove(obj);
>        _context.Save();
>         TempData["success"] = "Category deleted successfully";
>         return RedirectToAction("Index");   
>     }
>     public IActionResult UpSert(int? id)
>     {
>
>         //Product product = new();
>         //IEnumerable < SelectListItem > CategoryList = _context.Category.GetAll().Select(u=>new SelectListItem { Text = u.Name, Value = u.Id.ToString() });
>         // IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CoverTypeList = _context.CoverType.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.Name, Value = u.Id.ToString() });
>         ProductVM productVM = new()
>         {
>             Product = new(),
>          CategoryList =    _context.Category.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.Name, Value = u.Id.ToString() }),
>          CoverTypeList =  _context.CoverType.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.Name, Value = u.Id.ToString() })
>
>
>         };
>         
>         if (id is null or 0)
>         {
>             //create product
>
>             //ViewBag.CategoryList = CategoryList;
>             //ViewBag.CoverTypeList = CoverTypeList;  
>             return View(productVM);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             //update product
>         }
>       ;
>         return View(productVM);
>     }
>     [HttpPost]
>     public IActionResult UpSert(ProductVM obj, IFormFile? file)
>     {
>         
>
>         if(ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
>             if(file !=null)
>             {
>                 string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
>                 var uploads = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, @"images\products");
>                 var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
>                 using(var fileStreams = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName + extension),
> ```
>
> FileMode.Create))
> {
> file.CopyTo(fileStreams);
> }
> obj.Product.ImageUrl = @"\images\products" + fileName + extension;
> }
>
> ```
>             _context.Product.Add(obj.Product);
>             _context.Save();
>             TempData["success"] = "Product  update successfully";
>             return RedirectToAction("Index");
>         }
>         return View(obj);
>         
>     }
>     #region API CALLS
>     [HttpGet]
>     public IActionResult GetAll()
>     {
>         var productList = _context.Product.GetAll();
>         return Json(productList); 
>     }
>         
>
>     #endregion
> ```

`r code here`ckquote`
changed the return as you have showing but the pagge saying loading but it never load

[first screen shot of the controller][2[secon screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BFes.png)\I'm new to coding world I'm trying to load my data form my database using DataTables, but for some reason I keep getting this error message. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Trying to load the data from my database but it seems like my configuration is not working

Comment: add response from controller

Comment: Add Responce format.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow baba! it would be nice if you could post code instead of screenshots. also, show us the controller code.

Comment: You shouldn't attached screenshot, you must share the code snippet, it stackoverflow, requirement and convension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Trying to load the data from my database but it seems like my
> configuration is not working

I have reproduced your issue accordingly. This might be happend due to many reasons, if your data not in correct `json format` or if your column fields are in wrong format for instance, UpperCase, LowereCase.

In your scenario, you are doing wrong here:  `return Json(new { data = productList});` as per your view code, you should return like this  `return Json(productList);` so your error will resolve.

You can try this way:

**How to Debug:**

[image]

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var productList = new List<product>()
            {
                new product(){ Id = 1, Title = "A", ISBN = "ISBN-1", Price = 10.1},
                new product(){ Id = 2, Title = "B", ISBN = "ISBN-2", Price = 10.1},
                new product(){ Id = 3, Title = "C", ISBN = "ISBN-3", Price = 10.1},
                new product(){ Id = 4, Title = "D", ISBN = "ISBN-4", Price = 10.1},
                new product(){ Id = 5, Title = "E", ISBN = "ISBN-5", Price = 10.1},



            };

            return Json(productList);

        }
```

**Model:**

```
public class product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Price</th>
           

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Admin/Product/GetAll",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#myTable').DataTable({
                        data: response,
                        columns: [
                            { data: 'id' },
                            { data: 'title' },
                            { data: 'isbn' },
                            { data: 'price' }
                        ]
                    });

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Output:**

[image]